# Drop down search by tags input

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm trying to build a search by tags input box that's similar to the demos by Xoxco found here

http://xoxco.com/projects/code/tagsinput/example.html

I would have used his project from github but my implementation is within an already existing app that breaks when I import his project into mine.

So currently i've got most of basic features up and running at http://jsfiddle.net/Newtt/3eHXN/2/.

Currently when i click on an option it appears in the search box. My question is that how do I make more than one item appear and secondly, how do I style the words that appear inside the search box after clicking?

For the second question, I was thinking of something like:

```
$('.options`).click(function(){
    var c = $(this).html();
    var a = c.css('background':'#ccc',
                  'color':'#000',
                  'width':25px');
    $('#search-by-tags').val(a);
});
```

It doesn't work in Fiddle so I was wondering where I'm going wrong and how do I correct it?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

**[Working Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/3eHXN/3/)**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
            $('#search-by-tags').focus(function(){
                $('#input-tags').show('slow');
            });
            $('#search-by-tags').blur(function(){

            });
            $('.options').click(function(){
                var currentval=$('#search-by-tags').val()
                if(currentval!="")
                $('#search-by-tags').attr('value', currentval+','+$(this).html());
                else
                 $('#search-by-tags').attr('value',$(this).html());
                $('#input-tags').hide('slow');
            });
            $('#search-button').click(function(){
                $('#search-by-tags').attr('value','');
                 $('#input-tags').hide('slow');
            });
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

For this i have changed little bit, like i have declared a global array `arr` which holds the value selected by user, You can try this updated one:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
   var arr = []; //<-----------------------------declare a global array here
   $('#search-by-tags').focus(function () {
      $('#input-tags').show('slow');
   });
   $('#search-by-tags').blur(function () {

   });
   $('.options').click(function () {
      arr.push($(this).html()); //<------------push the selected item
      $('#search-by-tags').val(arr);  //<------place the current array arr
      $('#input-tags').hide('slow');
   });
   $('#search-button').click(function () {
      $('#search-by-tags').val('');  //<------use .val('') to make it blank
      $('#input-tags').hide('slow');
  });
});
```

#### [Demo Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/3eHXN/4/)

#### Note:

instead of using `.attr()` this way:

```
$('#search-by-tags').attr('value',$(this).html());
```

you can try this as suggested in the answer above using `.val()`:

```
$('#search-by-tags').val(arr);
```